# How to implement a path with more than one subdomain using Pux.Router?

Tags: purescript, purescript-pux

I'm using `Pux.Router` and can't get a path such as `auth/facebook` to work. `auth` works and `facebook` works but not together. For example `FacebookAuth <$> (lit "facebook" *> param "access_token") <*> (param "expires_in") <* end` works but not `FacebookAuth <$> (lit "auth/facebook" *> param "access_token") <*> (param "expires_in") <* end`. It will compile but you cannot navigate to `auth/facebook`.

Comment: Could you post the code declaring the `Facebook` type, and the full matching code?

Comment: Do you mean `FacebookAuth` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Pux.Router, but my thought is that you can only use single path components inside `lit`, so having nested components in a single string won't work.

You might try separating the paths like this...

```
FacebookAuth <$>
  (lit "auth" *> lit "facebook" *> param "access_token") <*>
  (param "expires_in") <* end
```

Which will apply the `access_token` and `expires_in` parameters to the FacebookAuth constructor. So then it would match `/auth/facebook/:access_token/:expires_in`

Comment: `FacebookAuth <$> (lit "auth" *> lit "facebook" *> param "access_token") <*> (param "expires_in") <* end` returns error `Could not match type Unit with type String`.